# Where does Visual Studio 2010 store the “Recent Projects and Solutions” items for the File menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, recent-file-list

Where (in which file or which registry key) does Visual Studio 2010 remember the list of recently-opened projects and solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Studio\10.0\ProjectMRUList`.